# Local Azure Function Service Bus Trigger doesnt pick up messages but no information

Tags: azure, servicebus

I have a very frustrating issue

```
 [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
 public async Task MyFunctionAsync(
 [ServiceBusTrigger("%AzureTopicName%", "mysubscription", Connection = "event-bus-connection")] Message message)
 { 
    //My logic here
 }
```

This never gets hit

I have checked and verified all configuration and there are no issues

Messages are being written to the service bus which would not happen if there was a config issue

However, my trigger never gets fired even though messages are in the subscription

Has anyone ever seen this?

This is local execution not Azure

Paul

Comment: In my experience local testing not working is often down to the settings that VS Code or other IDE needs not being in place. Do you have a setting for that connection to the service bus in your local environment? Is your Service Bus using a private endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Validate the connection string, Subscription, Topic names used in the function code are correct.  Get Connection string from Service Bus Namespace to use in function code.

[image]

2. Check if the messages are moving to the dead-letter queue or the messages being processed by another function.

---

I have followed below steps and able to trigger the Service Bus Topic Triggered Azure function.

- Created a Service Bus Topic trigger Azure Function.
- Created a Service Bus, Topic and a subscription inside the Topic.

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "mysubscription", Connection = "demo")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "demo": "Endpoint=sb://<ServiceBus_name>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=GRWoe2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXbEd8Ing="
  }
}
```

- Sending the messages:

[image]

Console Output:

```cs
Functions:

        Function1: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-03-31T10:41:54.990Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-03-31T10:42:15.389Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=b57524a6-4fb8-4586-9bfb-c88e23d137bb)
[2024-03-31T10:42:15.394Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 129a51488e34478db8ff88c43308da8b, SequenceNumber: 1, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-03-31T10:42:12.1620000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2024-03-31T10:43:12.2400000+00:00, SessionId: (null)
[2024-03-31T10:42:15.433Z] C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: Hello
[2024-03-31T10:42:15.490Z] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=b57524a6-4fb8-4586-9bfb-c88e23d137bb, Duration=205ms)
```